# How to divide by infinity in MathCAD

Tags: mathcad

Could anyone recommend a proper way to work with infinite values in MathCAD? For example when calculating resistances. If I use the infinity constant I get a floating point error.

```
w := 314.159 s^-1
C := \infinity F

X.C := 1/wC
```

I have to use large value for the C (10^10) and cope with the X.C being small and not exactly zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Infinit is symbolic concept. Try to use symbolic calculations like that:

[image]

In my practice if I know that number may be too small I add TOL to it.